# Ms Graph http call to get profile picture/photo is slow when user has no picture/photo

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When I try to get the profile photo of a user which has no photo it takes 4s - 8s  in average until I get a 404 error.

When the user has a photo the response time is much faster. Is this something general or is this maybe a problem in our environment?

You can easily reproduce this by using [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and with a call to a user which has no photo:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userid}/photo/$value
```

Edit: Found that is slow for users which have no licence. But this should still not take 4s-8s.

Comment: I suspect this is an error and likely stemming from it attempting to find a photo from multiple potential sources. Does the call for just the metadata respond quicker (`/photo` without `/$value`)?

Comment: Yes the call to /photo is faster then /$value but still between 2s - 3s. I found out that when a user has a exchange license the query is below 1s.

Comment: The reason it takes less time if they have Exchange is this is where Graph is pulling the photo from. If it's taking 4-8 seconds, it sounds like it's timing out when attempting to find the user's mailbox.

Comment: If I want to change the photo in the Office 365 admin center there is message that only users with an exchange license can have a photo. So I'll probably check if the user has an exchange plan before I try to get his photo, but this is sth the backend could also do to respond faster.

Answer (score 0):

The team haven't judge if the user have exchange license but retrieve the photo from all possible sources directly until get an valid result.If user have photo, we don't need to retrieve all sources so it will faster. You can submit an [feature request](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) for this issue.

Comment: Thanks but I have the feeling that user voice is not really maintained from the graph team. The are entries from 2014 without feedback and the newest feedbacks are from 2017. Do you know there any other place which is more visible for such requests ?

Comment: The opened thread for graph is 2018/5. So there are some guy will follow the case but not every day/not regular. https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=101632. I am not sure you have saw which thread